# Creating a condition to generate a column from other two columns

Tags: r, data.table

How can I create a column in a dataset conditioned to  other two columns according to this example.

On this example I am showing all possible combinations from my data:

```
library(data.table)
data <- "chr start tag depth BCV
    chr1 3273 chr1-3273 0 0
    chr1 3274 chr1-3274 1 1 
    chr1 3275 chr1-3275 1 2
    chr1 3276 chr1-3276 1 3
    chr1 3277 chr1-3277 2 1
    chr1 3278 chr1-3278 2 2
    chr1 3279 chr1-3279 2 3
    chr1 3280 chr1-3280 3 1
    chr1 3281 chr1-3281 3 2
    chr1 3282 chr1-3282 3 3"
    data <- read.table(text=data, header=T)
```

Expected outcome:

```
newdata <- "chr start tag depth BCV states
chr1 3273 chr1-3273 0 0 0
chr1 3274 chr1-3274 1 1 1
chr1 3275 chr1-3275 1 2 2
chr1 3276 chr1-3276 1 3 3
chr1 3277 chr1-3277 2 1 4
chr1 3278 chr1-3278 2 2 5
chr1 3279 chr1-3279 2 3 6
chr1 3280 chr1-3280 3 1 7
chr1 3281 chr1-3281 3 2 8
chr1 3282 chr1-3282 3 3 9" 
newdata <- read.table(text=newdata, header=T)
```

The requested column in the data.table (states) ranges from 0 to 9 depending on the combination of the other two columns.

Comment: So you are just trying to add a row index to your aggregated data or you want to add a grouping index to duplicated values in two columns? From your example one could think/solve both ways.

Comment: I am trying to add a row index with aggregated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP is not well phrased. I'm guessing your looking for:

```
setDT(data)[, states := .GRP - 1, by = .(depth, BCV)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R,

```
data$states = as.numeric(factor(paste(data$depth, data$BCV))) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this gives you the desired table:

```
setDT(data)
data[, states:=.I-1]
data
```

To ensure the order of your records with respect to the two columns `depth`and `BCV` you can set keys in the datatable before the `data[, states:=.I-1]`.